# Exists check takes forever in Django SQLite

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, lookup

I am running a webservice where a user sends a word as a request, and I use that word to filter entries in my database (the default Django SQLite). The relationship word-to-entry is one-to-one.
That means there are two possible cases:

1. The word exists in the database -> Return the associated `Entry`.
2. The word doesn't exist -> Throw exception.

The following lookup should then return a QuerySet with 1 or 0 objects:

```
Entry.objects.filter(word__iexact=word)
```

### Expected Behavior:

Cases 1 and 2 do not differ perceptibly in speed.

### Current Behavior:

- Case 1 takes at most half a second.
- Case 2 takes forever, around 1-2 minutes.

I find this puzzling. If an existing `word` can be looked up regardless of where it is in the database, then why does case 2 take forever? I am not a django or database expert, so I feel like I'm missing something here. Is it worth just setting up a different type of database to see if that helps?

Here is the relevant portion of my code. I'm defining a helper function that gets called from a view:

**mysite/myapp/utils.py**

```
from .models import Entry

def get_entry(word):
    if Entry.objects.filter(word__iexact=word).exists():
        queryset = Entry.objects.filter(
            word__iexact=word
        )  # Case insensitive exact lookup
        entry = queryset[0] # Retrieve entry from queryset
        return entry
    else:
        raise IndexError
```

Comment: How many entries are in your database?

Comment: Keep in mind that SQLite is generally not used for serious web apps in production. It's mostly a convenient tool for development.

Comment: Helper functions promote bad code. This is one example: your entire helper function can be reduced to one line with a cleaner api: `Entry.objects.filter(word__iexect=word).first()`, which returns None or the item. Now, why are you raising IndexError?

Comment: @AlexHall, a few million.

Comment: @Melvyn, thanks for the tip but that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: That's why I used a comment. And I asked a question, cause I suspected you were using the IndexError to "try again" and that there's no difference, but a loop running after a fail.

Comment: Your query essentially scans the table looking for a matching entry. If it finds one it can stop looking early, but if it doesn't it has to go through the entire table. I suspect that it *does* matter where the word is in the table, and that for certain existing words the query will still take a long time. You can try searching for "django sqlite case insensitive index" or something like that to make these queries faster.

Comment: @Melvyn Ah I see. No, the index error is actually kind of a placeholder, as it gets raised as a bad request in the view anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal, especially with a few million records on sqlite and I'm assuming without an index.

A missing word will always have to go through **all** records if there is no usable index. A word that is found, will terminate once found. There's no noticable difference if the word you are looking for is the last word in table order.

And it's actually because you're using a slice, so the slice uses LIMIT and database can stop looking at first match.

Comment: Does that mean I'm best of just biting the bullet and installing a different database?

Comment: You should at least put an index on the field. But I wouldn't sleep easy with millions of records in sqlite. Sorta feels [like this](https://i2.wp.com/www.curbsideclassic.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/africa-overloaded-passengers-truck_3023038k.jpg).

Comment: Maybe add that to the answer for others to see it